# jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js is not loading correctly via Webjar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot, webjars

I'm a bit new to coding. My question is the same as the title.
I'm working on javaEE web project in my `pom.xml` I have this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery.inputmask</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and in my `layout.html` I loaded all my js paths like this :

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="/webjars/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="/webjars/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
<!-- jquery.inputmask -->
<script src="/webjars/jquery.inputmask/min/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="/js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

everything is working fine except jquery.inputmask, it's not working no effect on my input text (no masking no mouseover event). Why?

thank you for trying to help me there is an image from console as you asked[Click me for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBC7f.jpg)

here is the code when im using it but the input text is not changing acting like a regular input text no masking no mouseover event and also im using thymeleaf as template engine to view the page.

```
          <!-- form input mask -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
              <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Input Mask</h2>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                  <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">
                   </i></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
                    toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i 
                 class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="x_content">
                <br />
                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-
           3">Date Mask</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-
       inputmask="'mask': '99/99/9999'">
                      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" 
            aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-
                   3">Phone mask</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-
             inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" 
                 aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-
           3">Custom Mask</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-
           inputmask="'mask': '99-999999'">
                      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" 
           aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-
             3">Serial Number</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-
        inputmask="'mask' : '****-****-****-****-****-***'">
                      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" 
           aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-
              3">TaxID Mask</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-
        inputmask="'mask' : '99-99999999'">
                      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" 
          aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-
           3">Credit Card Mask</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" data-
       inputmask="'mask' : '9999-9999-9999-9999'">
                      <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback right" 
           aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
                  primary">Cancel</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
              success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /form input mask -->
```

Finally thank you all ,
Thank you very much , i got help from the plugin owner 
For the people wondering as NiK648 said below just add the inputmask in the pom.xml file

```
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
      <artifactId>inputmask</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.11</version>
       </dependency>
```

and this line in js part

```
 <script src="/webjars/inputmask/inputmask/bindings/inputmask.binding.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check your console to see if `jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js` is getting loaded.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me there is an image from console as you asked on the post

Comment: So it is getting loaded correctly. Can you add the code where you are invoking inputmask?

Comment: i added the code as you requested

Comment: I can see that you added the `data-inputmask` attributes to your inputs. But you also need to invoke `inputmask` on those inputs. See the official documentation here: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask.